# 22.04 Wifi adapter is not working, lshw -C network returns network 0: disabled

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP Probook 440 g8 and im having trouble connecting to the wifi.
It uses the Intel Wifi 6 AX201 wireless adapter,i think?
I have tried most of the methods suggested in the trouble shooting website
here's some details

#lshw -C network returned

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network:0 DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: 7c:21:4a:32:c7:c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600324c000-600324ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 20
       serial: 84:69:93:67:56:38
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=192.168.29.83 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:144 memory:54100000-5411ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

#lspci returned

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation XG6 NVMe SSD Controller
```

I tried using the ifconfig to turn the network to up

#sudo ifconfig wlp0s20f3 returned

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

#rfkill list all returned

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried restarting the NetworkManager that did not work.

#sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state returned

```
sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

I tried downloading the Intel AX201 wifi drivers and copied them to the firmware folder and rebooting,did not work.

Can anyone help?

edit:

sudo dmesg |grep iwl returned
[Grep result](https://github.com/was-siri-us/ubuntu-errors--/blob/2dfdefd3eab9fc3eca5bf5199ee056166cd20ee3/dmesg%20%7Cgrep%20iwl)

edit:[2](https://github.com/was-siri-us/ubuntu-errors--/blob/main/sudo%20dmesg%20%7C%20grep%20-%20e%20ucode%20-e%20iwl)

sudo dmesg | grep ucode returned

```
[    3.831451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[    4.015534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[    4.197068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   14.198578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   14.404207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   14.606410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   14.811832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   15.015151] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   15.219319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   25.203140] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   25.400231] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   25.605948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   25.811612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   26.010301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   26.216651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   36.164367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   36.366597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   36.550613] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   36.734928] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   36.945194] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   37.132614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   47.115652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   47.314559] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   47.518696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   47.723742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   47.927378] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   48.122884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   58.097701] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   58.302644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   58.506510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   58.704651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   58.906562] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
[   59.109313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
```

ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep QuZ-a0-hr-b0 returned

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1105668 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1103952 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1209628 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1223140 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1299660 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1328924 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1334804 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1344216 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1347524 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1355800 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1364308 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode
```

edit[3]:

ls -al /lib/firmware | grep QuZ-a0-jf-b0 returned

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1052608 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1053004 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1147104 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1163668 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1226064 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1248672 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1252744 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1262244 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1275264 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-68.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1285188 Oct  3 16:38 iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-71.ucode
```

edit[4]:
renamed the file and rebooted

sudo dmesg | grep -e ucode -e iwl returned

[dmesg output](https://github.com/was-siri-us/ubuntu-errors--/blob/main/sudo%20dmesg%20%7C%20grep%20-%20e%20ucode%20-e%20iwl)

edit:
The wifi was working fine when i was running ubuntu 20.4. It stopper working after i deleted ubuntu 20.4 and installed 22.4.

edit: sudo dkms status returned:

```
bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
```

edit:
tried sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source and rebooting

didnt help

Comment: You can not just copy a driver to that folder and it works. Did you look to see how to actually install a driver?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Uhh i followed some guide in which it said to copy the driver files into the firmware folder, then stopp and restart the network manager and reboot. It did not work, I don't know if thats the proper way of manually installing the driver though

Comment: added result of dmesg | grep iwl

Comment: Let's see exactly what firmware file is being used: `sudo dmesg | grep ucode` Then we'd like to know if it's corrupted: ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep QuZ-a0-hr-b0` We suspect that version 63 loads and its size should be 1334804.

Comment: added output of sudo demsg | grep ucode and ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep QuZ-a0-hr-b0

Comment: Please substitute: `ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep QuZ-a0-jf-b0`

Comment: added output for ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep QuZ-a0-jf-b0

Comment: Your firmware is not, as far as I can tell, corrupted; however, your *dmesg* shows many repeats of: "Microcode SW error detected." As an experiment, please rename your firmware file: `sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.bak`
` Reboot and show us: `sudo dmesg | grep -e ucode -e iwl` http://paste.ubuntu.com We can easily revert if needed.

Comment: renamed the file and added output of sudo dmesg | grep -e ucode -e iwl

Comment: We now see that firmware version -63, instead of -66, loads with the same result. We also notice: "Hardware error detected. Restarting." This is found in both *dmesg* logs, both before and after renaming the firmware file. We now suspect that it's a hardware issue. Does the wireless work with any other operating system? Windows?

Comment: @chili555   I was previously running ubuntu 20.04 on the same device and there were no network issues. I was gonna install windows on it but then just went with the new version of ubuntu and installed it after erasing the older version.

Comment: May we please see: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: @chili555 added sudo dkms status ouput

Comment: *bcmwl* is a Broadcom driver. Your device is an Intel. Please do: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot. Although I am skeptical, it might help.

Comment: @chili555yeah it did not work, lshw -c network still returns network 0 disabled and wifi isnt working

Comment: @chili555 also please let me know if it is possible for you to spare some time to chat to maybe like try fixing this in one go, if it's not too much trouble, thank you.

Comment: Please set up a room and give me the link. I'll be happy to help if I can.

Comment: No, I will not join your discord. Please go here instead: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140320/room-for-wintersolstice-and-chili555